# Google App Engine 1.7.5 - org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I created a sample GWT app with Google app engine -GAE, I created an entity and persisted it on the service layer, works OK, data stored.

So I started adding widgets and more classes, on my service layer, when I try to create the EntityManager, I get:

`org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException` for a non entity classes, e,g a widget, I don't know why Datanucleus is trying to enhance classes that do not have @Entity annotation.

I configured Google Plugin Eclipse, under ORM to only enhance beans in the dto package and remove /src entry.

It never work, I just need to be able to tell DN to not enhance just every class it sees its CLASSPATH.

Any help will be apprciated.

I am using GAE version 1.7.5 and GWT 2.5 and GXT 2.5.5.

Exception:

```
Initializing App Engine server
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war' is not an EAR directory. File C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war' is not an EAR directory. File C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war' is not an EAR directory. File C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper logNotAnEar
INFO: Directory 'C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war' is not an EAR directory. File C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\appengine-application.xmlappengine-application.xml not detected.
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\dev\tools\gae\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\dev\projects\org\me\workspace\lottoshop\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:57 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Mar 8, 2013 5:07:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.22 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/25.0.1364.152 safari/537.22
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.SearchResponse was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.FieldVerifier was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoType was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.TestData was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.server.LottoShopDAOServiceImpl was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.resources.Resources was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoShopServiceAsync was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.model.Customer was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.SearchRequest was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.GameTypes was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.icons.ExampleIcons was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.server.LottoShopServiceImpl was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoShopDAOServiceAsync was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.Lottoshop was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.AppEvents was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.server.EMF was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoShopService was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.Constants was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.MultiplePlayersFoundException was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.images.ExampleImages was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoShopDAOService was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.resources.TestData was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.Resources was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit
WARNING: Class co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.icons.ExampleIcons was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
Mar 8, 2013 5:15:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.dto.Player co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.client.LottoShopDAOService.find(java.lang.String) throws co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.shared.MultiplePlayersFoundException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.server.LottoShopDAOServiceImpl.find(LottoShopDAOServiceImpl.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:242)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:184)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
    at co.za.fwc.webapp.lottery.server.EMF.<clinit>(EMF.java:7)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when loading the MetaData for the persistence-unit "transactions-optional". See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:979)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialiseNucleusContext(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:754)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialise(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:417)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:380)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class "com.extjs.gxt.samples.resources.client.model.MailItem" was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.
    at org.datanucleus.JDOClassLoaderResolver.classForName(JDOClassLoaderResolver.java:245)
    at org.datanucleus.JDOClassLoaderResolver.classForName(JDOClassLoaderResolver.java:410)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:954)
    ... 56 more

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Just a tip to someone who finds him/herself in this predicament, so I completely abandoned project creation using   Google Plugin for Eclipse 3. and focused on using mvn, hopefully the enhance goal of mvn will work without any troubles.

Comment: Using mvn also posed some challenges but with prior experince of mvn, I managed to solve most. I am now getting Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl I am hoping @DataNucleus can come to my rescue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into similar problem, I am using GAE-1.7.7, GWT-2.5.1 and Hibernate Validator. As soon as I turned on validations, client side validations were running fine but server side persistence screwed up, showing similar ClassNotResolvedException Exception

Something is broken up in scanning of classes while building up the EntityManager. The solution is disabling the auto scanning of entities and explicitly telling which classes to load while building PersistenceUnit

please modify your persistence.xml and add the following lines just below the `<provider>` tag

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>your.package.Entity1</class>
    <class>your.package.Entity2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

This should work.